# Timestamp parsing in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
df1:

Timestamp:

1995-08-01T00:00:01.000+0000
```

Is there a way to separate the day of the month in the timestamp column of the data frame using pyspark. Not able to provide the code, I am new to spark. I do not have a clue on how to proceed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can parse this timestamp using unix_timestamp:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
df2 = df1.withColumn('Timestamp2', F.unix_timestamp('Timestamp', format).cast('timestamp'))
```

Then, you can use dayofmonth in the new Timestamp column:

```py
df2.select(F.dayofmonth('Timestamp2'))
```

More detials about these functions can be found in the pyspark [functions documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions).

Comment: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"` will work correctly, because `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"` return null value.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
df1.select(dayofmonth('Timestamp').alias('day'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working on Apache Spark 3.2.1

I have tried the following:

- format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
- format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"

Both of the format didn't work for me, what worked for me is the following

- format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz"

I have seen another difference too for using `unix_timestamp` before `to_timestamp`, here are the findings

- If you use `unix_timestamp` - your original timestamp will loose anything after .

  - For example 2024-02-11T20:07:28`.099`+00:00 this will change to 2024-02-11T20:07:28`.000`+00:00
- Whereas if you don't use `unix_timestamp` and use the following instead you will be able to retain everything

`df = df.withColumn("ConvertToTimestamp", F.to_timestamp("StringTimestamp", format))`